# No DLL dependency Mingw under Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I'm trying to get back to C++ using Mingw and Netbeans but all released .exe requires some .dll files if ran on another PC.

What should I do to add those library to the released .exe file. [I do not have too much experience in real C++ programming]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please tell us what dll's are missing. but often you can find them in the `bin` folder of mingw. If you release your program, put those dll's where your exe is.

Alternative: use static linkage

### Edit:

1. You can get this file from the `bin` folder of your mingw installation. Copy it to your exe
2. Compile with linker flags: `-static-libstdc++` and `-static-libgcc`

Comment: "...libstdc++6.dll was not found.."

Comment: See my edit. Are you using any 3rd party libraries or frameworks?